# Tossing a biased and a fair coin

Tags: probability

Every morning Alice tosses a biased coin (giving head with probability $p$). If it comes up head, she wears a red shirt. If it comes up tail, she tosses a fair coin (giving head with probability $1/2$): if it comes up head she wears a red shirt, and otherwise she wears a white shirt.

1. What is the probability that today Alice wears a white shirt?
2. Given that Alice is wearing a red shirt, what is the probability that the first coin has come up head?
3. It is known that Alice wears a red shirt with probability $5/8$. What is the value of $p$?

In my opinion, the answer to the first question is $\frac{1-p}{2}$. In fact, we have 4 possible cases, respectively occurring with probability $\frac{p}{2}$, $\frac{p}{2}$, $\frac{1-p}{2}$ and $\frac{1-p}{2}$ (I think of pairs, where the first component is the probability of coming up head/tail with the first coin). Is my argument correct? What about the two successive answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**
The response to your first question is correct, but instead of listing out all scenarios you can just use conditional probability, as this question seems to be based on that:

Let $P(W)$ be the event of wearing a white shirt and $P(R)$ that of a red shirt. We know that the first toss has $P(H_1)=p$ and $P(T_1)=(1-p)$. The fair coin toss has $P(H_2)=P(T_2)=(1/2)$. Note that the second toss only occurs if $P(T_1)$ occurs, so really we have $P(H_2) = P(H_2 | T_1)$ and $P(T_2) = P(T_2 | T_1)$.

With these specifics out of the way, we can address $P(W)$ as the probability that $P(T_2)$ occurs which is equal to $= P(T_2 | T_1)P(T_1) = (1/2)(1-p) = (1-p)/2$ as per your description.

**Question 2**
Moving forward, the second question seems to make use of Bayes' Theorem. We can model this as the following: $P(H_1|R) = P(R|H_1)P(H_1)/P(R)$. To find $P(R)$ we note that in the end there are only two outcomes: White or Red, and so $1 - (1-p)/2 = (2-1+p)/2 = (1+p)/2 = P(R)$. We also recall that Red occurs on the first heads (aka $P(RH_1)$) with $p$ probability. So we translate our Bayes' Theorem calculation to $P(H_1|R) = p / ((1+p)/2) = (2p)/(1+p)$.

**Question 3**
Building on the previous two answers, we see that if $P(R) = 5/8$, we can substitute for the answer through algebra. $P(R) = (1+p)/2$ and therefore $5/8 = (1+p)/2$ so we get $5/4 = 1+p$ and therefore $p = 1/4$.